# Redmine imap email field overrides

Tags: redmine

I've finally got Redmine configured to receive issues via imap with one issue, I can't get  the "Due date:" field to work. I have my rake command set to `allow_overrides=all` so it should take all of them from the email. I have them in the body of the email like this:

```
Project: project1
Due date: 02/20/2022
```

I can get it to accept all of them except this one. Project, assigned to, tracker, etc. I've tried various formats to get the date field to accept but to no avail, I've tried:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
mm-dd-yyyy
yyyy/mm/dd <---it's stored in the database this way but still doesn't come through
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, hopefully this will be of use to others if needed. Due date is defined like this:

`Due date: yyyy-mm-dd`

The function that goes through the email to figure out which keywords to use for overrides is at `/path/to/redmine/app/models/mail_handler.rb'` and starts at line 425 (on Redmine 4.2.1). This shows the expected values for other fields as well if you're trying to figure out another one.